# How to fill color in the inside transparent portion of vector drawable without filling color in the outside rectangualar bounds of it?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

[image]

In the above vector drawable, I can modify the tint of the solid portions of the drawable using say green color and apply it using PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP. But I can't seem to apply a color inside the drawable like in the drawable's eyes. If I try different modes I can just see the color apply across the entire rectangle bounds of the drawable. Is there a simple trick I'm missing here?

Also I can't have the target eye color in background because in my case there is another drawable in the background and if I had to apply red color to the eyes, then I've trace out the outline of the drawable and make that entire thing as solid red and put this drawable on top of it. I'm not sure how to create a drawable with just the outline as well, It seems there is only an option that comes with rectangular bounds and nothing like to follow along the outline of the drawable image.

I do not want to create another vector drawable and hoping I can do something programmatically to get the job done. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't fill in just the eyes there AFAIK, but you could add small colored circles to the drawable behind them. The eyes are just another area with nothing drawn on it.

Comment: Yeah I thought about the same idea on having the target eye color behind this drawable but again i don't want to calculate the exact pixel positions of the eyes. Is there a way to get the entire vector drawable outline and fill it with target color? So that I dont have to calculate the eye postions and just simply put this drawable above the outline drawable?

Comment: You would have to edit the path definitions, which is probably no easier. If you do, you could copy the current path but omit the eyes, then color that and draw the original one over it.

Comment: If you share the drawable XML in the question it would help make this actually answerable.